# UIImage Rotation custom degrees

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, image-manipulation

I have been using the code in this sample to assist and this works well.
http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2009/03/30/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-mirroring/

I cannot workout how to rotate by a custom amount of degrees between 0 & 360....

Comment: I'd recommend an iphone tag here…

Comment: Great piece of code.  Doesn't do arbitrary rotation, but it is efficient and handles image orientation with mirroring very well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll want to do pretty much the same stuff as in that post does in rotate:

```
CGSize size = sizeOfImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, angleInRadians);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, (CGRect){{}, size}, image);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

You might need to also translate the CTM in addition to rotating to compensate for the center of rotation. If you want to not crop the edges of the image when rotating, you should increase the size with some basic trig.

Comment: `ctx` is just the graphics context. I updated the source to indicate that.

Comment: @AndrewPouliot:That is really great.But how do i set the center of rotation for the image?

Comment: @Shantanu: CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -centerOfRotation.x, -centerOfRotation.y), rotate, then CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, centerOfRotation.x, centerOfRotation.y);

Comment: Why do you store a reference to the current graphics context with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`, and then run `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` again two lines later?

Comment: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() returns nil and thus the image is nil. How would you solve this problem?