# Combine 2 UIImages as one, one of them is rotated

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I'm getting at one point with iOS. I have 2 UIImage which are bgImg & img. BgImg is actually the background image, img is a smaller one which places in the bgImg' bounds.

I need to combine 2 of these images as one, called finalImg. The problem is img should be rotated in a select angle. I have done so many tests with no result. If you have any ideas, please help me. What I need is just to return the combined image.

Thanks so much, my fellow iOS developers.
Thang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a graphics context, draw your two images to it, and then capture a new image from the context, as described in this post:
[Saving 2 UIImages to one while saving rotation, resize info and its quality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7092276/852828)

If you don't already have the rotation of your foreground image worked out, then the first answer to that post should help you as well.