# Image became horizontal after successfully uploaded on server using Http Post

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

i capture the image using image picker, at the that time image is in its actual position. but after uploading it on server it became horizontal. i don't get any clue why that happening.

here is my code

```
    NSString *urlString = @"Url";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // file
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   // [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"user_photo\"; filename=\"photoes.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",@"ImageNmae"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:ImageDesc.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is a problem with MAC/WINDOWS os reading differently. If you see that photo on MAC you will see its orientation as you uploaded only and still same image will show as rotated on WINDOWS. We have faced similar issue previously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i find  the solution here is code.

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image { // here we rotate the image in its orignel 
int kMaxResolution = 640; // Or whatever

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);


CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = roundf(bounds.size.width / ratio);
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = roundf(bounds.size.height * ratio);
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same orientation issue when image is uploaded to server. does the code will correct my orientation issue on my server.

Answer (score 2):

The orientation (rotation in your case) is in the exif data of your image.
You need to pre-rotate the images on the iOS or post-rotate them on your server.

On iOS you can check the `imageOrientation` property of [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can get the transform with that code snipped (you need to set a size or change the code part. Size could be the original size):

```
- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:           // EXIF = 3
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:   // EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, newSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:           // EXIF = 6
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:   // EXIF = 5
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:          // EXIF = 8
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  // EXIF = 7
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, newSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:     // EXIF = 2
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:   // EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:   // EXIF = 5
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  // EXIF = 7
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
    }

    return transform;
}
```

Of course your need that to apply the transform somehow to your UIImage. But i think you will find that in other questions on stackoverflow. Maybe start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102474/rotate-uiimage-custom-degree).

Answer (score 1):

its being a nice query for the media uploading.

When you capture the Image from your device it fix the orientation for the particular Image.
suppose you capture image in landscape mode & when you show this with your imageView it displays itself in portrait mode because basic Device configuration does both of Support for the Image (landscape & portrait) then it might pretend itself as portrait While actually stored in landscape. As result it saves over server in landscape While you displaying image in portrait in your UI (imageView).
finally 1) image was written horizontally on device.
        2) you have shown it vertically on UI due to portrait mode active for Application.
        3) But When it will be written on server it takes its original mode(horizontal).

So as per best suggestion you should display the Media in proper mode in Application.

Answer (score -5):

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);
```

Isn't the 90 a rotation angle ?

**Edit after reading docs**

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);
```

Looks like 90 should be 0.9. Might not be the problem though.