# How can I rotate UIImage on clicking rotate button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, rotation

I would like to rotate UIImage not the UIImageView on clicking rotate button not on orientation change. Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

use
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW37
for IOS 4 , if you want to rotate image

or you can use: http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2010/01/31/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-scaling/

or

- http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/

Comment: i dont want to rotate image view i need to rotate iamge and than save it

Answer (score 1):

```
CGSize size =  sizeOfImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, angleInRadians);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
  CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, size.height),
  image);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

Comment: can please let me know what will come in foll:
sizeOfImage
image(in cgrectmake)

Comment: you should declare source where you had copied. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917713/uiimage-rotation-custom-degrees/918794#918794.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` (available from 4.0)