# Orientation Change of UIView based on two points

Tags: iphone, math, geometry, rotation

First post here, great site!

Basically, Im trying to rotate a UIImageView based on two points. Imagine the two points form a line going across the screen. I need the angle of the UIImageView to match the angle of that line...

Heres a diagram of what Im trying to say as its quite hard with words:

http://i40.tinypic.com/t5k2yr.png

Thanks for your time!

Comment: These might help: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108768/ios-pinch-scale-and-two-finger-rotate-at-same-time), [link 2](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html)

Comment: Hmm those links seem to cover gesture recognisers, I was hoping to do the auto-rotation without any user input.

Comment: Use an `NSTimer` to change the angle of rotations and use the angle with transforms to make the rotations.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont fully understand what you mean. I believe that I first need to find the angle of the line generated by the two points, and then rotate the uiimageview to match that angle. Im not sure how those links help?

Comment: Those links were when I thought you need to rotate based on multiple-touch. Go through [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917713/uiimage-rotation-custom-degrees) instead

Comment: Finding the angle of the line is easy enough: atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) for x2!=x1.  If x2=x1, your angle is 90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get the atan() part but I'm not too sure about the "for" part. Would you mind explaining it a little for me?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1));
```